# Failed building wheel for pandas on model 3B+

Tags: python, pi-3b+, packages, pip, gcc

I'm trying to install `pandas` in a Python virtualenv on a RPi model 3B+,
but its wheel fails to build.

Pandas does however successfully build/install for the system Python (`py3.7.3`, `pip 18.1`).

Could anyone suggest a possible solution or an approach to finding one? Ideally I would like to keep using `py3.8` (this and other projects sometimes use its new features quite a bit), and also use `pyenv` and some virtual environment to allow testing multiple versions as well as keeping my project dependencies nicely separated.

**Further basic information:**

- I'm simply running the command `pip install pandas` with my venv activated.
- I'm running in a python 3.8.6 virtualenv (located in `/home/pi/knifbot/kenv/`, in case that's relevant).
- I'm using `pyenv` to manage my python installations.
- `pip --version` output: `pip 21.1.3 from /home/pi/knifbot/kenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip (python 3.8)`
- Ran updates first (`sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade`).
- The virtualenv is named 'kenv'

**What I've tried so far:**

I tried running the part directly preceeding the error to see if I could get more detailed error output
than just `command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1`, but that fails because I think there are
relative/temporary paths in here which don't exist running from a different working directory:

```bash
(kenv) pi@wolrpijoost:~/knifbot $ gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -fPIC -DNPY_NO_DEPRECATED_API=0 -Ipandas/_libs/src/klib -I/tmp/pip-build-env-1via64rh/overlay/lib/python3.8/site-packages/numpy/core/include -I/tmp/pip-build-env-1via64rh/overlay/lib/python3.8/site-packages/numpy/core/include -I/tmp/pip-build-env-1via64rh/overlay/lib/python3.8/site-packages/numpy/core/include -I/tmp/pip-build-env-1via64rh/overlay/lib/python3.8/site-packages/numpy/core/include -I/tmp/pip-build-env-1via64rh/overlay/lib/python3.8/site-packages/numpy/core/include -I/tmp/pip-build-env-1via64rh/overlay/lib/python3.8/site-packages/numpy/core/include -I/tmp/pip-build-env-1via64rh/overlay/lib/python3.8/site-packages/numpy/core/include -I/home/pi/knifbot/kenv/include -I/home/pi/.pyenv/versions/3.8.6/include/python3.8 -c pandas/_libs/join.c -o build/temp.linux-armv7l-3.8/pandas/_libs/join.o
gcc: error: pandas/_libs/join.c: No such file or directory
gcc: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
```

**Seemingly relevant parts of stderr/stdout streams:**

```bash
Building wheel for pandas (PEP 517): still running...
Building wheel for pandas (PEP 517): finished with status 'error'
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
command: /home/pi/knifbot/kenv/bin/python /home/pi/knifbot/kenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/in_process/_in_process.py build_wheel /tmp/tmpt3d47g7q
cwd: /tmp/pip-install-82lpukxn/pandas_6a67c5eaea2148a9a6d445ba4bc4c63b

... 

A lot of files being copied for compilation + succesful compilations for some extensions here.
(Link to full dump below).

...

building 'pandas._libs.join' extension
gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -fPIC -DNPY_NO_DEPRECATED_API=0 -Ipandas/_libs/src/klib -I/tmp/pip-build-env-1via64rh/overlay/lib/python3.8/site-packages/numpy/core/include -I/tmp/pip-build-env-1via64rh/overlay/lib/python3.8/site-packages/numpy/core/include -I/tmp/pip-build-env-1via64rh/overlay/lib/python3.8/site-packages/numpy/core/include -I/tmp/pip-build-env-1via64rh/overlay/lib/python3.8/site-packages/numpy/core/include -I/tmp/pip-build-env-1via64rh/overlay/lib/python3.8/site-packages/numpy/core/include -I/tmp/pip-build-env-1via64rh/overlay/lib/python3.8/site-packages/numpy/core/include -I/tmp/pip-build-env-1via64rh/overlay/lib/python3.8/site-packages/numpy/core/include -I/home/pi/knifbot/kenv/include -I/home/pi/.pyenv/versions/3.8.6/include/python3.8 -c pandas/_libs/join.c -o build/temp.linux-armv7l-3.8/pandas/_libs/join.o
gcc: fatal error: Killed signal terminated program as
compilation terminated.
error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
----------------------------------------
ERROR: Failed building wheel for pandas
Building wheel for numpy (PEP 517): started
Building wheel for numpy (PEP 517): still running...  
Building wheel for numpy (PEP 517): finished with status 'done'
Created wheel for numpy: filename=numpy-1.21.0-cp38-cp38-linux_armv7l.whl size=17206572 sha256=44a3a3e5ad25b338dca8a9580b354fdddd9097e55759576122eef6224c7a8eec
Stored in directory: /home/pi/.cache/pip/wheels/60/65/cf/1eb6d9255266eea1d6ffddce9ebc4f388bcc8460d616f17eb0
Successfully built numpy
Failed to build pandas
ERROR: Could not build wheels for pandas which use PEP 517 and cannot be installed directly
```

[Link to full dump on pastebin.](https://pastebin.com/K8QtVGgf) <sub>(Will be automatically removed 2022-01-13)</sub>

**Output of `cat /etc/os-release`:**

```bash
PRETTY_NAME="Raspbian GNU/Linux 10 (buster)"
NAME="Raspbian GNU/Linux"
VERSION_ID="10"
VERSION="10 (buster)"
VERSION_CODENAME=buster
ID=raspbian
ID_LIKE=debian
HOME_URL="http://www.raspbian.org/"
SUPPORT_URL="http://www.raspbian.org/RaspbianForums"
BUG_REPORT_URL="http://www.raspbian.org/RaspbianBugs"
```

**Last lines of `cat /proc/cpuinfo`:**

```bash
Output of 
Hardware    : BCM2835
Revision    : a02082
Serial      : 000000007d01c596
Model       : Raspberry Pi 3 Model B Rev 1.2
```